# How to extract a subchain from a string in Oracle, starting with a specific known pattern

Tags: regex, oracle, varchar

I need to extract all words starting wiht the pattern "**B0D_**" in this following example and have the result as a single string made up of all the values ​​found separated by a semicolon without blank. All the data coming from an Oracle table.

```
INPUT : HP-003 [R8003 A - R8003 B] AND (**B0D_A5** AND DMW_11) OR (**B0D_C5** AND DMW_11) OR (B0E_003) 

OUTPUT : B0D_A5;B0D_C5
```

I have a little preference for regexp.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean you would *slightly opt for* regexp or you have a *very little preference* for them?

Comment: I prefer to use regexp,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single `regexp_replace` will be good enough.

The pattern `(.*?)((B0D\w+)|$)` defines the first group as a *non-greedy* for the uninteresting characters before the word.

The second group is (nested) either the searched word or end of the line.

The  `regexp_replace` picks *all occurences* (5th parameter = 0) of the *third group* (the word) and appends a semicolon.

So at the end you must *trim* the trailing semicolon(s).

The query with some additional test data

```
with tab as (
select 'INPUT : HP-003 [R8003 A - R8003 B] AND (B0D_A5 AND DMW_11) OR (B0D_C5 AND DMW_11) OR (B0E_003)' col from dual union all
select 'INPUT : HP-003 [R8003 A - R8003 B] AND (B0D_A5 AND DMW_11) OR (B0D_C5 AND DMW_11) OR (B0E_003) B0D_A6' col from dual union all
select 'INPUT : HP-003 [R8003 A - R8003 B] AND (B0D_A5 AND DMW_11) OR (B0D_C5 AND DMW_11) OR (B0E_003) B0D_A6B0D_FIN' col from dual
)
select 
   rtrim(regexp_replace(col,'(.*?)((B0D\w+)|$)','\3;',1,0),';') b0d_lst
from tab

B0D_LST
---------
B0D_A5;B0D_C5
B0D_A5;B0D_C5;B0D_A6
B0D_A5;B0D_C5;B0D_A6B0D_FIN
```

Comment: Thanks to you both. The above solution fully satisfies me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option (sample data in lines #1 and 2; query you need begins at line #3). It finds all `B0D%` strings in a hierarchical query and concatenates them using `LISTAGG`.

```
SQL> with test (id, col) as
  2    (select 1, 'HP-003 [R8003 A - R8003 B] AND (B0D_A5 AND DMW_11) OR (B0D_C5 AND DMW_11) OR (B0E_003)' from dual
  3     union all
  4     select 2, 'ASX (SDR) AND (XAZ AND B0D_F23F)' from dual)
  5  select id,
  6         listagg(regexp_substr(col, 'B0D\w+', 1, column_value), ';')
  7           within group (order by column_value) result
  8  from test cross join table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
  9                                           connect by level <= regexp_count(col, 'B0D')
 10                                          ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 11  group by id
 12  order by id;

        ID RESULT
---------- ------------------------------
         1 B0D_A5;B0D_C5
         2 B0D_F23F

SQL>
```

Comment: Perfect. How to adapt this request to have a similar result foreach entry of my table?

Comment: In a similar fashion. I edited that example; have a look.

Comment: How can I use your solution to have an unique semicolon separated enumeration of the searched word ?